# How do I select a specific child with a common class in a unique parent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Just like the title says, I want to select a specific common class of a unique parent's child in JavaScript. I want to use `textContent` and append that to a specific child with a common class without it going to other parents.

I've thought of several ways in my own way but all of it involves modifying the entire code which in my perspective is incredibly inefficient.

As example of what I want to do:
I want to target `task-item2` 's `task-title` . I could do this by using the querySelect properties but it just ends up going to the first selected class as per its nature(e.g `task-item1` 's `task-title`).

Is there a way to do this without having to resort to unique child classes in JavaScript?

```
<div id="task-item1">
  
  <div class="task-checkbox"></div>
  <div class="task-title"></div>
  <div class="task-description"></div>
  <div class="task-date"></div>
  <div class="task-delete"></div>
  
</div>
```

```
<div id="task-item2">
  
  <div class="task-checkbox"></div>
  <div class="task-title"></div>
  <div class="task-description"></div>
  <div class="task-date"></div>
  <div class="task-delete"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: *"I could do this by using the querySelect properties..."*: did you try `document.querySelector(".task-item2 .task-title")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just chain the selectors:

```js
document.querySelector('#task-item2 .task-title').textContent = 'my title';
```

```html
<div id="task-item1">
  
  <div class="task-checkbox"></div>
  <div class="task-title"></div>
  <div class="task-description"></div>
  <div class="task-date"></div>
  <div class="task-delete"></div>
  
</div>

<div id="task-item2">
  
  <div class="task-checkbox"></div>
  <div class="task-title"></div>
  <div class="task-description"></div>
  <div class="task-date"></div>
  <div class="task-delete"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I can't believe I forgot the very fundamentals of this.